# How to combine query for two tables in one dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net

3 Points
65 Posts
How to combine query for two tables in one dropdownlist?
a few seconds ago|LINK

Hi..

I have two tables and two gridviews. Table SCEMPR for gridview1 and table WSCEMPR for gridview2. Both tables has the same column. Its just different data. That is why I need different gridview.

I have dropdown list for selecting the months. Whenever I select the dropdownlist, the record in both gridviews should be changed according to the selection. But my problem is that, I only can make a query for table SCEMPR (for gridview1). How can I make another query for table WSCEMPR? Should I combine it or make a different query?

below is my code. Pls help..

Page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="False" Font-Size="10pt" Height="20px" Width="194px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged" style="margin-left: 0px">
<asp:ListItem Text="SELECT MONTH" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList></td>
```

Server end:

```
// query ddl for month
string queryddl2 = "SELECT DISTINCT CASE RIGHT(RTRIM(QMBSTEST.SCEMPR.SPMTH), 2) WHEN '01' THEN 'January' WHEN '02' THEN 'February' WHEN '03' THEN 'March' WHEN '04' THEN 'April' WHEN '05' THEN 'May' WHEN '06' THEN 'June' WHEN '07' THEN 'July' WHEN '08' THEN 'August' WHEN '09' THEN 'September' WHEN '10' THEN 'October' WHEN '11' THEN 'November' WHEN '12' THEN 'December' ELSE '' END as SPMTH FROM QMBSTEST.SCEMPR";

connection = new OdbcConnection(@"Dsn=as400;Uid=FATIN;Pwd=FATIN;");

OdbcDataAdapter oda2 = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryddl2, connection);
DataSet dset2 = new DataSet();
oda2.Fill(dset2);
ddl2.Items.Clear();

ddl2.DataSource = dset2;
ddl2.DataValueField = "SPMTH";
ddl2.DataTextField = "SPMTH";
ddl2.DataBind();
ddl2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("ALL MONTHS", "ALL"));
```

Comment: For your script in supplying the value for the dropdown, use UNION since it has same field as you have said.

Comment: @Stuart can I use union eventhough the gridview is different?

Comment: Create a seperate script for the value for the dropdown since you will be using UNION. I suggest, create a view for gridview1 and gridview2 then use this view for UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION

```
SELECT 'FirstTable',col1,col2 FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT 'SecondTable',col1,col2 FROM Table2
```

You can then parse the set based on the 'TableX' column if you need to bind some of it to one gridview and the rest to the other.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
//FOR WSCEMPR
string queryddl1 = "SELECT DISTINCT CASE RIGHT(RTRIM(QMBSTEST.SCEMPR.SPMTH), 2) 
                    WHEN '01' THEN 'January' WHEN '02' THEN 'February' WHEN '03' THEN 'March' 
                    WHEN '04' THEN 'April' WHEN '05' THEN 'May' WHEN '06' THEN 'June' 
                    WHEN '07' THEN 'July' WHEN '08' THEN 'August' WHEN '09' THEN 'September' 
                    WHEN '10' THEN 'October' WHEN '11' THEN 'November' WHEN '12' THEN 'December' 
                    ELSE '' END as SPMTH FROM QMBSTEST.WSCEMPR";

//FOR SCEMPR
string queryddl2 = "SELECT DISTINCT CASE RIGHT(RTRIM(QMBSTEST.SCEMPR.SPMTH), 2) 
                    WHEN '01' THEN 'January' WHEN '02' THEN 'February' WHEN '03' THEN 'March' 
                    WHEN '04' THEN 'April' WHEN '05' THEN 'May' WHEN '06' THEN 'June' 
                    WHEN '07' THEN 'July' WHEN '08' THEN 'August' WHEN '09' THEN 'September' 
                    WHEN '10' THEN 'October' WHEN '11' THEN 'November' WHEN '12' THEN 'December' 
                    ELSE '' END as SPMTH FROM QMBSTEST.SCEMPR";

string qryForDropdown = queryddl1 + " UNION " + queryddl2;

connection = new OdbcConnection(@"Dsn=as400;Uid=FATIN;Pwd=FATIN;");

OdbcDataAdapter oda1 = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryddl1, connection);
OdbcDataAdapter oda2 = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryddl2, connection);
OdbcDataAdapter dDown = new OdbcDataAdapter(qryForDropdown, connection);

DataSet dset1 = new DataSet();
DataSet dset2 = new DataSet();
DataSet dsetDropD = new DataSet();

oda1.Fill(dset1);
oda2.Fill(dset2);
dDown.Fill(dsetDropD);

ddl2.Items.Clear();

ddl2.DataSource = dsetDropD;
ddl2.DataValueField = "SPMTH";
ddl2.DataTextField = "SPMTH";
ddl2.DataBind();
ddl2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("ALL MONTHS", "ALL"));
```

Comment: If u got the answer from this posted answer then plz mark as Accepted! As @Stuart have spent some time to resolve your issue..! :)